# Fusing learners with preprocessing in mlr - what settings to use?

Tags: r, benchmarking, data-cleaning, mlr

I am conducting a benchmark analysis comparing different learners (logistic regression, gradient boosting, random forest, extreme gradient boosting) with the `mlr` package.

I understand that there are two different types of preprocessing (data and learner dependent and independent). Now I would like to conduct the data dependent preprocessing using the `mlr`'s wrapper functionality `makePreprocWrapperCaret()`.

However, I am unsure about the settings. As far as I understand correctly, I should impute missings with median (or mean) for logistic regression, however for tree-based models for example with very great values.

**Question 1) How would I impute NAs with very great values in the code below (for the tree-based models)?**

Next, as far as I understand correctly, I should cut off outliers for the logistic regression (e.g. at 99%, and 1%). However, for tree-based models that is not necessary.

**Question 2) How can I cut off outlier (e.g. at 99%, and 1%) in the code below?**

Lastly, (again, if I understood correctly) I should standardize the data for the logistic regression. However, I can only find the "center" option within the `makePreprocWrapperCaret()` which is not exactly the same.

**Question 3) How can I standardize in the code below?**

Many thanks in advance!!

```
lrn_logreg = makePreprocWrapperCaret("classif.logreg", method = c("medianImpute")) #logistic regression --> include standardization + cutoff outliers
lrn_gbm = makePreprocWrapperCaret("classif.gbm") #gradient boosting --> include imputation with great values
lrn_rf = makePreprocWrapperCaret("classif.randomForest") #Random Forest --> include imputation with great values
lrn_xgboost = makePreprocWrapperCaret("classif.xgboost") #eXtreme Gradient Boosting --> include imputation with great values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the mlr tutorial for imputation: https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/impute.html

**1)**
You can use the `makeImputeWrapper` of mlr. For the maximum you can use `imputeMax` in `makeImputeWrapper`.

**2)**
For cutting of the highest and lowest values you can write your own preprocWrapper: https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/preproc.html

**3)**
For normalization there is already a preprocWrapper function: `normalizeFeatures`.
See also here: https://mlr.mlr-org.com/reference/normalizeFeatures.html